# Simple past VS Perfect

Tags: tense, past

When I tell someone about my childhood for example -
What will be correct? Or can I use both tenses?

Als ich 16 war, ging ich auf eine Privatschule.

Or

Als ich 16 war, bin ich auf eine Privatschule gegangen.

Comment: Less formal: _Mit 16 war ich auf einer Privatschule._

Answer (score 2):

Since you usually go to a school over a long period of time, you would use perfect. However, *gehen* is a verb including movement, so you use *bin* instead of *habe*. Also, it is the *Privatschule* and the Präposition should be *auf* instead of *zu* (if the *gehen* means that you are enrolled in that school).

Correct version:

*Als ich 16 war, bin ich auf eine Privatschule gegangen.*

Example with simple past:

*Als es 20:00 Uhr war, ging ich zu Tina.*

Comment: What about "Als es 8 Uhr was, bin ich zu Tina gegangen". Works as well?

Comment: It is a bit colloquial. If you write a formal letter, you would use the simple past, but in a conversation nobody will care if you use the perfect there.

Comment: This can be generalized, too. Most of the time, perfect ist used orally, and simple past in written language. However, there are exceptions, e.g. "sein".